# Wrong Titles and Description displaying in Google Search Results for ReactJs App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meta-tags

For Google SEO we have implemented Server Side Rendering for React Js (using nodejs) and provided Title and Description in Meta Tags but somehow google is showing wrong title and description.

We tried Server Side Rendering with Node Js and whenever we inspected in https://metatags.io/ and other 3rd party apps but we are getting perfect results but google is not picking the right title as well as description.

Any other suggestions or improvements are welcome

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Google can take a few days to reindex your page. Just wait for a few days and it should update.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

But it's not reflecting since its is almost more than 15 days.

We have used Node.js  as Server side rendering